# Use of find elements in Selenium using Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium

Can anyone please help me find how can I write find elements method in Ruby and click on first element ? I tried this but did not work.

```
sl=driver.find_elements(:xpath, "//*[@title='Women']")

sl[0].click
```

The error given is as follows

```
undefined method `click' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: The same xpath is working for you in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use find with css selector:

```rb
driver.page.find('[title="Women"]').click
```

Comment: But there are 4 similar elements with title women. Hence I used find elements method. I used that in similar manner in Java, Python. Not getting what and how to use find elements in Ruby.

Comment: find('[title="Women"]').click is doing exactly find_all('[title="Women"]')[0].click